# CSS: box-shadows overlapping during scrolling

Tags: css

I added a shadow around my menu and the content, when the content are scrolled the shadows are overlapping.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewe5eg59/4/

```
<div class="menu">menu</div>
<div class="content">content</div>

body {
    margin-top: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
div.menu {
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:blue;
}
div.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

How can I fix this?

**SOLVED** (Thanks to Anahit Ghazaryan):

http://jsfiddle.net/ewe5eg59/34/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="menu">menu</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

body {
    margin-top: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
}
.wrap {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px black;
    height:1046px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
div.menu {
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 6px;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black; */
    z-index: 100;
}
div.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 46px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will replace the div.content margin to padding your issue will be solved!Here is the code

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="menu">menu</div>
   <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

And the Css

```
body {
margin-top: 0;
}     
.wrap{
 width: 100px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px black;
height:1039px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  }   div.menu {
   width: 100px; 
}
div.menu {
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-top: -3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black;
  z-index: 100;
  }
  div.content {
width:100px;
height: 1000px;
background-color: yellow;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: I updated this in fiddler but then I have the explained overlapping problem on top of the menu on the last pixel where the shadow is getting weaker. UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/ewe5eg59/17/

Comment: Thank you, I changed it a little bit and update the solution in the question.